# Relatorio de cliente em MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

Boa tarde senhores, tudo bem?
Estou enfrentando um problema e não estou conseguindo resolve-lo.

Abaixo segue um exemplo da estrutura do meu banco de dados:

[image: exemplo de como encontra-se a estrutura do banco de dados]

Preciso fazer um script em MYSQL que selecione as pessoas que contenham as seguintes condições:

1 - PESSOA_ENDERECO.UF = "MS"

2 - PESSOA_EMPRESTIMO.DATA_TERMINO > NOW()

3 - PESSOA_EMPRESTIMO.TIPO_EMPRESTIMO = 'CARTAO'

4 - PESSOA_EMPRESTIMO.CODIGO_BANCO = '0001'

(essa é a parte que não estou conseguindo)
5 - QUE POSSUAM UMA MARGEM DISPONÍVEL SUPERIOR A UMA PORCENTAGEM ESPECIFICA;

A margem disponível é calculada da seguinte forma:

35% do valor que encontra-se em PESSOA_BENEFICIO.VALOR menos a soma de todos os VALOR_PARCELA do beneficio em questão.

ou seja: se a pessoa recebe 1300 de beneficio, a margem dela é 455;
a margem disponivel dela seria 455 menos a soma de todas as parcelas dos emprestimos que ela possui.

Comment: Seja bem vindo ao Stack Overflow! Por favor, insira o código da consulta que você já criou até o momento. Isso pode ajudar a achar uma resposta.

Comment: Acabei de sair do trabalho, amanhã no primeiro horário posto o script que eu tenho até o momento!

Comment: select 

 `pessoa`.*

from `pessoa_endereco` 

 left join `pessoa` on `pessoa`.`id` = `pessoa_endereco`.`pessoa_id` 
 right join `pessoa_emprestimo` on `pessoa_emprestimo`.`pessoa_id` = `pessoa`.`id` 

where 

 `pessoa_endereco`.`estado` = 'MS' and 
 `pessoa_emprestimo`.`banco` = '0001' and 
 `pessoa_emprestimo`.`tipo_emprestimo` = 'CARTAO' 

group by `pessoa_id` limit 10